# REST best practice cloud

Tags: rest, authorization, ibm-appid

I have a set of REST services on IBM cloud. Ingress is integrated with Appid for authentication. Ingress adds the token id & access id to the authorization header. 
Now on the API side (springboot) do I need to validate the user again on every request ? will this be redundant ? If no,  which appid api can be used to authorize the user. Any reference to similar example

Already gone through the example on IBM cloud site. One is about ingress & appid integration, but does not talk about REST services layer how to handle the authorization tokens there. 
Another is only about spring and Appid, (does not talk about ingress)

Answer (score 2):

Authentication versus Authorization is where the line is drawn. The Ingress integration with App ID does the authentication for you and your REST service (application) can be assured that the request if it comes through is authenticated. Now just because the user exists in your system and has provided the right credential does not mean that he is allowed to access the service he is trying to access or view the data he's trying to view which is where the authorization comes into play - the REST service can use the authorization tokens to figure out if the user has the right access to use the service.

Here's a good article that talks about the use of Roles - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/appid?topic=appid-tutorial-roles

Comment: Did this answer your question? Can you mark this as answered or upvote if it did?

Answer (score 0):

In any application - REST, UI or otherwise - multiple levels of security may be necessary depending on your requirements. Authentication verifies the user is who they claim to be, authorization checks what permissions the user might have. Each application might have its own rules for what the user can access.

In your case, you have authenticated the user facilitated via Ingress with AppID, which supplies a user principal (identity) to your application. However, should every user have access to all of your application endpoints? If the answer is no, then you will need an authorization model, for which a common approach is RBAC (role-based access control).

Even without an RBAC requirement, it is still wise the validate the user's principal in some form for each request. For example, perhaps the user belongs to a domain that you might not expect, or should no longer have access to this specific REST application. Your application server may have features that assist you with a simple authorization feature, or you can custom build your own validation.

At present, as the identity provider, AppID can be the store of the user's role for RBAC. However your application or application server must decide what to do with that role.

If you are looking for a Cloud-centric authorization solution, you may want to consider exploring Istio's authorization policies:

- https://istio.io/docs/concepts/security/#authorization-policy
- https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-istio